# Serving static files in development mode

Tags: django

I've read the documentation of the Django about [serving static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/), and it says you should use `django.conf.urls.static.static` function in order to server them. 
Here is my code:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from settings import STATIC_ROOT, STATIC_URL

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^api/v1/', include('news.rest_urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    static(STATIC_URL, STATIC_ROOT)
]
```

And this is the error I receive:

> 'list' object has no attribute 'regex'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT in settings.py and add to your urlpatterns next:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```